# Dynamic cell height causing bounce effect when calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

**Background**: In a tableView, each cell contains a button shown as an image. The effect I wanna show is that when I click the image(button actually), the button's image change to another one.
**Bug**: Say there are many data (over one page), and if I click one cell's button, the button's image will change BUT with a side effect that the whole tableView will first scroll up a little bit(like a bounce effect) then scroll down to the former place.
**What I've done**:

1. in ViewDidLoad method:
   `inboxListTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
   inboxListTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
2. When I clicked the button (true and false represent different image and the definition in tableView(cellForRowAtIndex:) method):

   ```
   let cell = sender.superview?.superview as InboxListCellTableViewCell
       if let indexPath = inboxListTableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
           let actionToUpdate = actions[indexPath.row]
           actionToUpdate.imageButton = !actionToUpdate.imageButton.boolValue
           var e: NSError?
           if !MOContext.save(&e) {
               println(e?.description)
           }
       }
   ```
3. Then in Fetch Result Controller Delegate method:

   ```
   func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
       inboxListTableView.beginUpdates()
   }

   func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
       switch type {
       case .Insert:
           inboxListTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       case .Delete:
           inboxListTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       case .Update:
           inboxListTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
       default:
           inboxListTableView.reloadData()
       }
       actions = controller.fetchedObjects as [Action]
   }

   func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
       inboxListTableView.endUpdates()
   }
   ```

I think the bug may caused by two aspects: CoreData and Self sizing cells (dynamic cell height). Because I didn't hit the bug when I use array to hold actions ([Action]) instead of CoreData. However, when I comment `inboxListTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` this code, it didn't "bounce back/ scroll up" but the height of the cell is fixed.

Any ideas? Anything can help! Thank you:)

Comment: I notice that you have row animation `.None`. Why?

Comment: @Mundi At first I set it to '.Fade' and still had this problem, so I changed it to '.None' thought it may work.

Comment: It has to do something with your update logic. You are changing a boolean attribute of the managed object. Based on that you are showing imageA or imageB. Perhaps you should add your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to the question.

Comment: As for now, I can make the button's image change when I click the button, and I configured cell's content in cellForRowAtIndex method. The problem is everything is correct but the tableview will bounce up a little bit :( But thank you anyway! @Mundi

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem: a little bounce when using dynamic cell heights. The difference in my case is that I didn't use NSFetchedResultsController and I also changed the heights of the cells (expand and collapse them).

After a lot of experimenting I've found a simple solution. Just call scrollToRowAtIndexPath after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths. It worked for me.

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
```

I call this code when I expand and collapse the cells.
I hope you can use this in your project.

Comment: Simple and great solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the pragmatic solution to your problem is to simply **not** use the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method for this particular update.

You can change the image of the button directly in the button handler. You have to check for this situation in the `.Update` case of the fetched results controller delegate and make sure you **don't** call the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method.

Now you are avoiding the automatic UI-update mechanism and the issue should not occur.

BTW, it is very bad practice to rely on the table view cell's view hierarchy for accessing the index path (`superview.superview...`). A few years ago, Apple changed the way cells work and code that relied on similar paradigms broke. The same with collection view cells.

Instead, do something like this:

```
func buttonHandler(sender: UIButton) {
    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the method to get tableView!! But sadly the way that remove 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths' method might not work. I changed my code for two aspects followed your suggestion: 1 I delete '.Update' switch case. 2 In buttonAction method, I changed the sender(UIButton)'s image using `sender.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), forState: .Normal)`. And now, at the runtime, the corresponding button's image can successfully changed, but tableView still scroll up a little bit like before.. Thank you!

Comment: Besides, this bounce effect didn't show when I use fake data(store the tableView datasource in an array), and I used `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method at that time. Thank you very much!!  @Mundi